# How to check 2 expressions inside a decode function in PL SQL

Tags: plsql, decode

Is it possible to check multiple Expressions inside "Decode" function in PL SQL.
My requirement is basically

```
SELECT value1,
DECODE(Expression1 AND Expression2,
       search1 , search2,
        ,'pass result',
        'fail result') value2
FROM dual;
```

Or is there are workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest answer is don't use decode, use a case statement instead, e.g.

```
select 1 value1,
       case when 'a' = 'a' and 'b' = 'b' then 'pass'
            else 'fail'
       end result
from   dual;

    VALUE1 RESULT
---------- ------
         1 pass
```

It is possible to use DECODE, but you'd have to use nested DECODEs and you'd end up with something that's much harder to read, understand and therefore maintain. And what happens if you need to add a third condition? Or maybe there are multiple sets of results that would result in a pass? You'd end up with something truly horrendous to try and understand!

But, if you really must, here's an example (along with the corresponding CASE expression solution, which is (IMHO) much easier to read):

```
with sample_data AS (SELECT 1 ID, 'a' col1, 'b' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, 'a' col1, 'c' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID, 'd' col1, 'b' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 4 ID, 'e' col1, 'f' col2 FROM dual)
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN col1 = 'a' AND col2 = 'b' THEN 'pass'
            ELSE 'fail'
       END case_result,
       DECODE(col1, 'a', DECODE(col2, 'b', 'pass',
                                      'fail'),
                    'fail') decode_result
FROM   sample_data;

        ID CASE_RESULT DECODE_RESULT
---------- ----------- -------------
         1 pass        pass
         2 fail        fail
         3 fail        fail
         4 fail        fail
```